# How to connect to oracle with sys and sysdba correctly?

Tags: oracle

I want to connect to oracle as sys user with sysdba privil..

How can I do it using easy connection

I am doing so:

```
sqlplus sys/password@server:1521/orcl as sysdba
```

and getting error:

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Is it correct syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `sqlplus sys/passsword as sysdba` where password should be `sys` password

Comment: okay, thank you. I think the problem with wrong password.

Comment: most likely because your syntax was ok. And You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect remotely as sysdba (port 1521 in your case). Connecting as sysdba from a remote location (over tcp or tcps) requires some extra steps:

1. Set the database parameter `REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE = { shared | exclusive | none }`.It should be set tp shared/exclusive.
2. Check your password file under $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/, which is being used for authentication when users login to the database as a sysdba. If the password file does not exist then create a new one (using orapwd) and set the password.