How to connect as admin in an existing connection in SQL Developer
I downloaded the Oracle DB Developer VM a while back and successfully created a new connection to connect to this VM in my SQLDeveloper app.  Currently this connection only has HR schema and I would like to install another Oracle schema from this Github link to the existing connection.
As you can see in the README.md file (from the provided link) it says that I need to connect as privileged user with rights to create another user (SYSTEM, ADMIN, etc.).
How do I connect to the existing connection containing the HR schema as an admin/system user to run the sql files?  I am logged in as 'HR' user in the existing connection and thus - as expected - I got ORA-01031 insufficient privileges error when I tried to run any of the sql files in the SQLDeveloper app.

Don't connect to the HR user. Create a new connection to the same database and use the SYS (or SYSTEM or ADMIN) user with the appropriate password and set the role to SYSDBA.

And for remote connection as SYS, also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886836/how-to-connect-to-oracle-with-sys-and-sysdba-correctly

Hi @MT0 - when I create a new connection aside from the user  do I use the same connection settings ?  It’s been a year actually since I set up the HR dabatase connection - is there a default SYS password and how do I reset it if I forgot the SYS password?

I am finally able to login as sys (please set the role = SYSDBA) in Sql Developer by creating a new connection - thanks to MTO for the tip!
